# Trigonometric substitution hint

Tags: calculus

I don't know how to get the following problem started and would appreciate a hint:

$$\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{9x^2+4}}dx$$

Comment: Recall that $\sec^2 \theta = \tan^2 \theta + 1$, and so if you wanted to integrate $(x^2 \sqrt{x^2 + 1})^{-1}$, that might lead to a fruitful substitution.

Comment: This looks very tricky. Perhaps $u = \arctan (\frac{3x}{2})$ will be a reasonable start.

Comment: Similar, you can take $x = \frac{2}{3} \;  \sinh t \; \; .$ There is also a version of the Weierstrass half angle trick that works for hyperbolic trig https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#Hyperbolic_functions  This leads to a rational function in some new variable, leading to polynomial division, perhaps partial fractions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write the integral as :

$$I=\int \frac{dx}{x^3 \sqrt{9+\dfrac{4} {x^2}}}$$

Now you can subsitute t = $9 + \dfrac{4} {x^2}$

$$
\begin{align}
dt &= -\dfrac{4}{x^3}dx \\
\dfrac{dt}{-8} &= \dfrac{dx}{x^3} \\
I&=\int \frac{dt}{-8 \sqrt{t}} \\
\end{align}
$$ 
This can be easily integrated !

In problems like these, sometimes you can get a very neat answer by taking x^n from the root.( I am unable to express it better and if you can write it better, please edit the answer.)

Comment: this actually seem like the most natural answer.... could you please elaborate on the final sentence, in particular "try taking dividing power of $x$ to get the derivative"....  I'm not clear on what exactly you mean

Comment: + 1 for your nice answer. I edited your answer but didnt correct the little mistake you made...$$dt=-8/x^3 dx$$

Comment: oh yes ! sorry about that. Thankyou for telling me that. I will edit it right away.

Comment: Please read the edited answer and tell me if this makes more sense to you. Otherwise i can try again.

Comment: The answer always made sense.....  that wasn't my point.  I wanted to know what your general strategy was.  In particular, what is $n$, in general?  Is there a pattern?  It does seem there is some pattern hiding in the background.

Comment: I understand your question. So most problems like these, which have a fractional exponent are designed in such a way that on making a few algebraic manipulations, the you can substitute the function under the fractional exponent and its derivative will be present in the numerator. I think you will be clearer about what i am saying if you could just try a few more problems like these. I have some but i don't know how to get them across to you.

Comment: You could post a hyperlink.....  or just recommend a textbook (chapter and section) if these problems are from a book you have.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kouba/CalcTwoDIRECTORY/powersubsoldirectory/PowerSubSol.html#SOLUTION%201

Comment: you can try these !

Answer (score 2):

$\int \dfrac{1}{3x^{2}\sqrt{x^{2}+\dfrac{4}{9}}}$

let  $x=\dfrac{2}{3}tan(u)$ so $dx=\dfrac{2}{3}(\sec^2 u)du$
$$I=\int \dfrac{\frac{2}{3}(\sec^{2}u)}{3\frac{4}{9} \tan^2u\sqrt{\frac{4}{9} \tan^2u + \frac{4}{9}}}du$$

$$=\int \frac{\sec^2 u }{\frac{4}{3} \tan^2u \sqrt{\sec^2u}}$$
$$=\frac{3}{4} \csc u\cot u du = -\frac{3}{4} \csc u + c$$

since $x= \frac{2}{3}\tan u$ it follows (draw a triangle) that $\csc(u)=\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+4}}{3x}$ and so the integral reduces to 
$$-\frac{\sqrt{9x^2+4}}{4x} +C$$

Comment: if you can not continue let me know! I can do more steps for you

Comment: if it is make sense to you, please accept my answer! its gonna be nice because I spent times for writing the solution

Comment: the derivative of $tan(u)$ is $tan^{2} +1$ and 2/3 is just coefficient

Comment: After double checking your work....  you seem to have a few mistakes.

Comment: where? the whole idea should work

Comment: well....  for one, your coefficient was $\frac{4}{3}$ but it should be $\frac{3}{4}$, and that is a minor point but also  the way you introduced $1+\tan^2(x)$ was odd because normally we think of $d(\tan)=\sec^2$ but you wrote it as $1+\tan^2$ then later use the fact that it's actually equal to $\sec^2$ so it just seemed like a obfuscation.  Of course, you're welcome to just edit it back as you like.

Comment: no the coefficient is right I just simplified. if you simplify all coefficient u wiil end up with 4/3

Answer (score 1):

Jagy's substitution is the best here

substitute $x=\frac 23 \sinh(t)$ and $ dx=\frac 23 \cosh(t)dt$
$$I=\int \frac{1}{x^2 \sqrt{9x^2+4}}dx$$
$$\int \frac{\frac 23 \cosh(t)}{\frac 49\sinh^2(t) \sqrt{4\sinh^2(t)+4}}dt$$
$$\int \frac{\cosh(t)}{\frac 23\sinh^2(t) 2\cosh(t)}dt$$
$$I=\frac 34\int \frac{dt}{\sinh^2(t) }=-\frac 34\coth(t)$$
Substitute back now...

Comment: I don't know $\int \frac{dt}{\sinh^2(t)} = \coth(t)$ off the top of my head, is this a pretty standard integral?

Comment: yes @Clclstdnt it's a standard integral but its $-coth$

Comment: I'm not well versed in taking the inverse of hyperbolic trig functions.  I know this is going to sound a little ridiculous.....  but could you finish this to its completion?  I don't know how to.....  If $x=\frac{2}{3}\sinh(t)$ then $t=\sinh^{-1}(\frac{3x}{2})$ and I read online elsewhere that $\sinh^{-1}(x) = \ln(x+\sqrt{x^2+1})$